# No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, railstutorial.org

I'm new to rails and currently having issues while working my way through the rails tutorial. I am on chapter 10 of the sample app. I checked to make sure the resources :users was included in the routes.rb configuration file, but I'm still coming up with this error - Please HELP!

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/edit".
```

running rails routes yields

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         static_pages#home
     help GET    /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
    about GET    /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
  contact GET    /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
   signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
         POST   /signup(.:format)         users#create
    login GET    /login(.:format)          sessions#new
         POST   /login(.:format)          sessions#create
logout DELETE /logout(.:format)         sessions#destroy
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
         POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

I have my files configured like so:

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                   'static_pages#home'
  get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post   '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
```

***/users/_form.html.erb***

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: yield(:url)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

***users/new.html.erb***

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Create my account') %>
<% provide(:url, signup_path) %>

<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

***users/edit.html.erb***

```
<% provide(:title, 'Edit user') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Save changes') %>
<% provide(:url, edit_user_path(@user)) %>

<h1>Update your profile</h1>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
     <div class="gravatar_edit">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank"    rel="noopener">Change</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing a PATCH to edit. You should be doing a PATCH to update.

```
<% provide(:url, user_path(@user)) %>
```

By convention you would normally call edit on your controller (GET method to edit_user_path(@user), which you are doing. This results in your edit.html.erb being rendered which in turn is rendering the form. The form itself should then invoke the update action on the controller (not the edit action) by PATCH method on users_path(@user). The url is the same as for the POST (when creating a new user) so you can remove the line

```
<% provide(:url, user_path(@user)) %>
```

and change form_for to just use users_path

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: user_path) do |f| %>
```

Note not to use 'users_path' as that links to users index an you will get an error since no PATCH method is available for that route.

Comment: I love you. I figured this part out eventually too, after shedding several tears.

Comment: Haha, I'm sure i'll have an entirely new wardrobe + donations by the time this tutorial is over. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: all instances of "users_path" here should be "user_path".

Answer (score 1):

@David had a good answer, however fixing it that way breaks the signup form (and its associated testing).
The way to fix it for this module is to change the provide in the edit.html.erb to the user-path, like so:

Change from:

```
<% provide(:url, edit_user_path(@user)) %>
```

to

```
<% provide(:url, user_path(@user)) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you are trying to access your edit controller action is not consistant with the routing pattern that you have already. Try this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                   'static_pages#home'
  get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post   '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  patch '/users/:id/edit', to: 'users#edit'
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: That's you're awesome, it works! I'm not receiving the routing error any longer, but the page doesn't perform the redirect_to @user after updating? I'll have to do another search! awesome!

Comment: No prob I am glad I could help feel free to accept the answer :)